# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.class

This is my build.gradle file. I could not resolve it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.raja.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'



 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'



  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'



  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'



 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all google play services should be using the same version - in your dependencies section, you can see you are not (some is 7.3.0, some is 9.8.0). Change it so they will all use the same version and try again.

Comment: i changed and compiled thanks. But now i got this error                                                         Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzanq.class

Comment: Try to remove the line:  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' and see what happens

Comment: I still think this must be a problem with the dependencies. How about the following - try to remove all the lines in your dependencies, then bring them back one by one trying to isolate what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `tools:node="merge"` into your `Application` Tag in manifest file like this:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon144x"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:node="merge"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

Hope it will solve the problem.